# Semi-Random Number Generation C++

Tags: c++, loops, random

I am running a Monte Carlo simulation where I generate 100,000 random paths. My problem is that I want to find a way to keep these same 100,000 random paths in loops of other variables. Essentially, I want my random number generator to reset each time I run my 100,000 iterations. Currently, I have code that looks something like this:

```
 vector<double>Rand_Var(double time)
 {
    static mt19937 generator;

    normal_distribution<>ND(0., 1.);
    ND(generator);
    double phi;
    vector<double> rand(time + 1);
    for (int i = 1; i <= time; i++)
    {
      phi = ND(generator);
      rand[i] = phi;        
    }

    return rand;
}
```

Then in `main()` for testing I have:

```
for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++)
{   
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
    {   
        vector<double>rand_val = Rand_Var(time_opt);            
        cout << rand_val[4] << endl;
    }
}
```

I get the following output:

```
-0.214253
 1.25608
-1.82735
 0.919376
 1.45366
-0.791957
 0.530696
 0.0751259
-0.559636
-0.709074
```

What I would like to get however is something like:

```
-0.214253
 1.25608
-0.214253
 1.25608
-0.214253
 1.25608
-0.214253
 1.25608
-0.214253
 1.25608
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried reseeding to the same seed? (ie: storing the current time in a variable and then repeatedly calling `.seed()` with that time every time you want a reset?)

Comment: why are you rebuilding the rand list each time you use it. When I saw that first function I thought, 'ok he is generating the randoms just once, expensive but certain to work'.  But you rebuild every time

Comment: @scohe001 -- make that an answer.

Comment: @pm100 That looks like a good answer.

Comment: Do you want `Rand_Var` to always return the same vector for the same `time` passed in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the same set of random numbers again, simply [reseed your generator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine/seed) to the same seed!

For example:

```
vector<double>Rand_Var(double time, bool should_reset) {
    static time_t my_seed = time(0);
    static mt19937 generator(my_seed);
    if(should_reset) { generator.seed(my_seed); } //reseed and reset!

    ...
```

And then in your loops:

```
for (...){
    bool should_reset = true;

    for (...) {
        vector<double>rand_val = Rand_Var(time_opt, should_reset);
        should_reset = false;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This just gives me the same value each time now. I am sure it is just something with how I have the code setup. I unfortunately do not know much about properly seeding my code.

Comment: @KWood don't you want the same set of values every time you call the function?

Comment: No its a bit  of a tricky situation. I want a combination of random numbers that repeats itself. In my inside loop say my first set of random numbers is : 6,10,2,1. Then I get a new set of random numbers 95,8,14,7. For my outside loop, I want to be able to regenerate these exact same "random" numbers each time. I am creating 100,000 demand paths that should be random, but I need to be able to regenerate those same 100,000 paths multiple times.

Comment: @KWood Please edit the question (and modify its example) to make this point clear. Chances are that you simply have to seed the generator once before calling the function that generates the 100000 * 260 values and use that seed for any successive calculation.

Comment: @scohe001 That looks like it worked! I appreciate that so much. I am going to run some tests and check, but this should save me significant amounts of time of not having to manually run my different parameters. One quick question, if I have quite a few nested loops with that rand_val part in the very center, should the bool should_reset=true be in the outermost loop?

Comment: @KWood -- `mt19937` (and any other "random-number generator" you see in a library) is more correctly called a **pseudo**-random number generator. The sequence that it generates is completely determined; it's "random" in that it's hard to guess what the next number will be from looking at a subsequence. So if you need to repeat a sequence of numbers, just restart the generator at the point where it started before. That's what the seed is about: seed it with a known value and generate as many values as you want; when you want to repeat the sequence, seed it again, with the same value as before.

Comment: @KWood pass `true` when you want the sequence to restart and `false` if you want to continue with "new" values. When and what you pass depends on what you want the behavior to be. If you only want to reset once every outer loop then only pass `true` once per every outer loop run.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a static variable, then it will be initialized once and generate new numbers all the time.

Just remove the static, and it will be initialized and use the same seed each time the function is called.

If you need more than one number (it's not clear what time does, is it an index or a value for the randomness?), pass the rng as the argument:

```
vector<double>Rand_Var(mt19937& rng, double time);
```

And create a new one in your first for loop.

```
for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++)
{
    mt19937 generator;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
    {
        auto rand_val = Rand_Var(generator , time_opt);
```

Comment: Sorry for clarification. This random number generator generates 260 random numbers that I use to simulate a demand path. Then I have 100,000 iterations of this demand path. I want each of the 100,000 demand paths to be different but want the same 100,000 paths each time I repeat the process.

Comment: So just put the random generator creation and seed set at the beginning of the 260*100000 random number generation. Just like here, and pass the random generator to the relevant functions. It could be wrapped in a class as well for better design.

Answer (score 0):

If you want every 100,000 random numbers to be the same then wrap the generator in a function and keep a counter. That would give you a random function like

```
double random()
{
    static std::mt19937 generator;
    static int counter = 0;
    if (counter % 100000 == 0) // reset every 100000 times.
        generator.seed();
    normal_distribution<> dis(0., 1.);
    counter++;
    return dis(generator);
}
```

If you want every 100,000 calls to `Rand_Var` to always return then you just need to do the same thing

```
std::vector<double> Rand_Var(std::size_t time)
{
    static std::mt19937 generator;
    static int counter = 0;
    if (counter % 100000 == 0) // reset every 100000 times.
        generator.seed();
    normal_distribution<> dis(0., 1.);
    counter++;
    std::vector<double> data;
    data.reserve(time);
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(data), time, [&](){ return dis(generator); });       
    return data;
}
```